# Два сайта на модекс - на одном отправляет почту, на другом нет

Tags: modx, email

Всем здравствуйте. Я только начинаю работать с Modx revolution. Такая проблема: сниппет

formlt.

на сайте такой код с формой для отправки почты

```
[[!FormIt? 
&hooks=`spam,email` 
&emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl` 
&emailSubject=`Сообщение от сайт- форма обратной связи` 
&emailTo=`почта` 
&errTpl=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[+error]]</div>`
&validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
&successMessage=`<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Все отправлено успешно!</div>`
&validate=`contact_name:required:minLength=`2`
, contact_email:email:required
, contact_message:required` 
&redirectTo=`9` 
]]
<div class="well">
<div class="lead">Форма обратной связи</div>
[[!+fi.successMessage]]
<form class="form-horizontal" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="contact_name">Ваше Имя </label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="form-control" id="contact_name" type="text" name="contact_name" value="[[!+fi.contact_name]]" size="30" />[[!+fi.error.contact_name]]</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="contact_email">E-Mail</label>
<div class="controls"><input class="form-control" id="contact_email" type="text" name="contact_email" value="[[!+fi.contact_email]]" size="30" />[[!+fi.error.contact_email]]</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="contact_phone">Телефон <em>(необязательно)</em></label>
<div class="controls"><input class="form-control" id="contact_phone" type="text" name="contact_phone" value="[[!+fi.contact_phone]]" size="14" maxlength="32" />[[!+fi.error.contact_phone]]</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="contact_message">Сообщение </label>
<div class="controls"><textarea class="form-control" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" rows="7" cols="90">[[!+fi.contact_message]]</textarea><br/>[[!+fi.error.contact_message]]</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
[[-!recaptchav2_render]]
[[-!+fi.error.recaptchav2_error]]
<br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<button id="loading" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Отправляем..." name="submit" value="Отправить"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Отправить</button>
<br/>
</div>
```

здесь работает

на втором сайте

```
</div> 
<div class="row"><!— CONTACT FORM —> 
<div class="twelve columns"> 
<div class="wrapcontact"> 
<h5>Форма обратной связи!</h5> 
<div class="done"> 
<div class="alert-box success">Форма обратной связи! <a class="close" href="http://сайт/">x</a></div> 
</div> 
[[!FormIt? &amp;hooks=`spam,email` &amp;emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl` &amp;emailSubject=`Сообщение от сайт - форма обратной связи` &amp;emailTo=`почта сайта` &amp;emailFrom=`почта сайта` &amp;errTpl=` 
<div class="alert alert-danger">[[+error]]</div> 
` &amp;validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!` &amp;successMessage=` 
<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Все отправлено успешно!</div> 
` &amp;validate=`contact_name:required:minLength=`2` , contact_email:email:required , contact_message:required` &amp;redirectTo=`11` ]] [[!+fi.successMessage]]<form id="contactform" class="form-horizontal" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post"> 
<div class="form"><label class="control-label" for="contact_name">Ваше Имя </label> <input id="contact_name" class="smoothborder" type="text" name="contact_name" value="[[!+fi.contact_name]]" size="30" />[[!+fi.error.contact_name]] 
<div class="six columns noleftmargin"><label class="control-label" for="contact_email">E-Mail <em>(необязательно)</em></label> 
<div class="controls"><input id="contact_email" class="smoothborder" type="text" name="contact_email" value="[[!+fi.contact_email]]" size="30" />[[!+fi.error.contact_email]]</div> 
</div> 
<div class="six columns noleftmargin"><label class="control-label" for="contact_phone">Телефон </label> 
<div class="controls"><input id="contact_phone" class="smoothborder" type="text" name="contact_phone" value="[[!+fi.contact_phone]]" size="14" maxlength="32" />[[!+fi.error.contact_phone]]</div> 
</div> 
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="contact_message">Сообщение </label> 
<div class="controls"><textarea id="contact_message" class="smoothborder ctextarea" name="contact_message" rows="7" cols="90">[[!+fi.contact_message]]</textarea><br />[[!+fi.error.contact_message]]</div> 
</div> 
<div class="control-group"> 
<div class="controls"><button id="loading" class="readmore" name="submit" value="Отправить" type="submit" data-loading-text="Отправка..."> Отправить</button></div> 
<div class="controls"> </div> 
<div class="controls"> </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</form></div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

здесь не работает, даже не возникает сообщение, что отправлено. пробовала ставить первый код - тоже не проходит.

Answer (score 0):

Глянь что выдает компонент [QuickEmail](https://modx.com/extras/package/quickemail) вызвав его на любой странице сайта(лучше тестовой) вот так:

```
 [[!QuickEmail? 
      &to=`твой_имейл@somewhere.com` 
      &debug=`1`
 ]]
```

Если письмо не отправится - то будет указана ошибка по которой письмо не отправлено.